How can i expand a cell to occupy entire row in a grid structure using css?
My page looks something like
|  A  |  C  |
|-----|     |
|  B  |     |
|-----|-----|

Problem statement is how can i expand div B to occupy the entire row Only if the height of div A is equal to that of div C?
Basically.. structure should be like below image ( only if height(A) == height(c) )
|  A  |  C  |
|-----|-----|
|     B     |
|-----------|

Problem with the 1st structure is that since the div C is made by combining 2 vertical cells as a result its height becomes dynamic ( dependent on A and B) ... As a result B never get the chance to expand on the entire row.
I also tried bringing C out from the grid structure so that its height becomes independent of A and B ... But that also didn't work as there will be only one column remaining so B doesn't have any place to expand .
can someone help me on how can we achieve the desired behaviour ?

If height(A) === Height(C) implies that you need to rely on JS for this. You may want to tag your question with [javascript]

Indeed, javascript is required.

What you can do is defining the placement of your grid containers in order to place them exactly where you want them to be.
In order to reach that you'll have to define the amount of rows and columns of your grid container and then set the "grid-column-start" and grid-column-end" (for row as well) for your containers inside.
Here is an example I created for you in Codepen so you can see what I mean.

.container-a {
/*CENTER TEXT*/
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background-color: blue;

/*GRID STYLING*/
grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;

}
Here is an example on Codepen
the command I used there for the containers A to C, grid-area, is a combination of the two I mentioned above. The order of the numbers is always "row-start / column-start / row-end / column-end".

Hi  ..
how the above code ensure that container B will be expanded only if height(A) == height(C) ... else it should maintain the original structure ??

What you could do is adding JavaScript code to your HTML.
I put the code into link I posted above.
What it does is simply comparing the "offsetHeight" of Container A and C.
If the Container have the same height it changes the area of B to stretch over the whole Grid Template. Is that what you mean?

actually that js will not work as container C is a part of the grid and made by combining two vertical cells so its hight will be dependent on container A and container B..
more precisely
height(C) will be always equal to  height(A) + height(B)  as per the above implementation

I think for that we'd need the code from you so we can look into it to evaluate the problem. Could you do that?

For item b you can add CSS style grid-column: 1/-1, which will let the item take the width of the complete row,
ref:[https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column.php][W3Schools]

item B needs to be expanded only if height(A) = height(C) ... else it should not expanded .. how can we ensure that ??
